# How to add row id of current user in upload

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5, devexpress, devextreme

I'm working in laravel PHP in dx grid dev extreme and I'm having problem while uploading imgae.
as image is saved in server but now i want to add image in db by getting users id while row is clicked...
how ever I need to update the image in db and frontend as well..[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/seE5d.png)

**Controller:**

```
public function uploadImg(Request $request)
{
    if($request['fileInput']) {
        $fileName = time().'_'.basename($_FILES["fileInput"]["name"]);
        $targetDir = "storage/users/";
        $targetFilePath = $targetDir . $fileName;

        $fileType = pathinfo($targetFilePath,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $allowTypes = array('jpg','png','jpeg','gif');

        if(in_array($fileType, $allowTypes)) {
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileInput"]["tmp_name"], $targetFilePath)) {

                return redirect()->back();
            } else {
                $response['status'] = 'err';
            }
        } else {
            $response['status'] = 'type_err';
        }
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
dataField: "avatar",
caption: "Add Image",
width: 200,
alignment: 'center',
formItem: {
    visible: false
},
width: 100,
alignment: 'center',
type:"button",
cellTemplate: function (container, options) {
    $("<div />")
    .text('Upload')
    .on('dxclick', function () {
        // alert('ok');
        $('#fileInput').trigger('click',function() {
            id: "users->id",
            $("#imageform").onValueChanged(function() {
                // uploadUrl: "{{route('upload')}}"
                $("#form").submit();
            })
        });
    })
    .appendTo(container);
    }
},
```

Comment: What about using the **file uploader** provided by the devexpress team already? https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/FileUploader/FileUploading/jQuery/Light/ . Besides, `users->id` sounds weird to me. Are you sure the above code is working as intended? Also, you can check this if you are using php: https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/Guide/Widgets/FileUploader/Upload_Files/Server-Side_Implementation_in_PHP/

Comment: this is giving error while tmp_name is not getting and not moving image at server side thats why i used php code in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 {
               dataField: "avatar",
               caption: "Add Image",
               alignment: 'center',
               formItem: {
                   visible: false
               },
               width: 60,
               alignment: 'center',
               cellTemplate: function(container, options) {
                   $('<a/ class="uploadfile" data-userid="' + options.data.id + '">').dxButton({
                           icon: 'upload',
                       })
                       // .text('Upload')
                       .on('dxclick', function() {
                           // alert($(this).data('userid'));
                           $('#userid').val($(this).data('userid'));
                           $('#myModal').modal('show');

                       })
                       .appendTo(container);
               }
```